# unable to read file in data block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am generating a file in the following way

```
resource "null_resource" "clone_manifest_argocd" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      echo "Clone ArgoCD main branch"
      git clone https://${var.gitlab_user}:${var.gitlab_token}@gitlab.com/org/k8s-argocd.git
      echo "Generate kustomize files for ${var.argocd_overlay} env"
      kubectl kustomize k8s-argocd/overlays/${var.argocd_overlay}/ -o /tmp/${var.argocd_overlay}.yaml
      cat /tmp/${var.argocd_overlay}.yaml
    EOT
  }
  triggers = {
    always = timestamp()
  }
}
```

The file is always being created and populated correctly

```
...
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec):     app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd-applicationset
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec):   name: argocd-applicationset-controller
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec): ---
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec): apiVersion: v1
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec): kind: ServiceAccount
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec): metadata:
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec):   labels:
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec):     app.kubernetes.io/component: dex-server
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec):     app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-dex-server
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec):     app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec):   name: argocd-dex-server
null_resource.clone_manifest_argocd (local-exec): ---
...
```

Now in order to deploy it, i want to use the kubectl provider. Ive setup it

```
provider "kubectl" {
  load_config_file       = false
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.eks_auth.token
}
```

and ive tried the following to get the YAML file and deploy it

```
data "kubectl_file_documents" "files" {
    content = file("/tmp/${var.argocd_overlay}")
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "test" {
    for_each  = data.kubectl_file_documents.files.manifests
    yaml_body = each.value
}
```

I also tried something like

```
data "template_file" "files" {
  template = file("/tmp/${var.argocd_overlay}.yaml")
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "public_alb" {
  yaml_body = data.template_file.files.rendered
}
```

but in either case, im getting

```
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 161, in data "template_file" "public_alb":
│  161:   template = file("/tmp/${var.argocd_overlay}.yaml")
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.argocd_overlay is "dev"
│ 
│ Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "/tmp/dev.yaml"; this
│ function works only with files that are distributed as part of the
│ configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in
│ this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of
│ that resource.
```

Is there something im missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Terraform [file function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/file) documentation:

> This function can be used only with files that already exist on disk at the beginning of a Terraform run. Functions do not participate in the dependency graph, so this function cannot be used with files that are generated dynamically during a Terraform operation.

You may want to try out the [Kustomize provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kbst/kustomization/latest/docs) rather than creating the file on the fly.

Comment: thanks, The Kustomize provider is of no use to me since I still need to generate the kubeconfig file. And if i can have a kubeconfig file, i can just point `kubectl` to it

Comment: You can also specify  a `kubeconfig` file with the kustomize provider,  or what do you mean?